# Problems Redirecting Tumblr with GoDaddy Domain

Tags: redirects, godaddy, tumblr

I am trying to get my website to redirect to a splash page. It is a Tumblr page with a custom GoDaddy domain: `example.com` that I am trying to automatically redirect here: `example.com/home`

When I tried to use the Forwarding feature on GoDaddy I had a lot of issues that I believe have to do with the fact that the website isn't actually being hosted on GoDaddy, but rather Tumblr. After I set the forwarding up my entire site went white with text saying that it was "temporarily unavailable". I removed the forwarding and it went back to normal.

I then tried to manually enter a redirect code into my Tumblr's html directly, but every time I try to hit "save" I get a "Whoops" message that disallows me from saving.

Total novice when it comes to coding but any advice???

Comment: Forwarding shouldn't care where a site is hosted, it is doing as it says, forwarding.

Comment: @Steve But "forwarding" to a particular page (as in `example.com/home`) is going to require an external redirect, which can only be done where the site is hosted.

Comment: Ah...I missed the /home :P

Answer (score 1):

You can't use anything like code changes or godaddy settings but I would like you to recommend that you may use a redirection service which redirects requests to help you what you want indirectly .
Take a bitly url or goo.gl url that redirects to example.com/home , let it be j .
Now set up redirection of your domain to the url j we just set before .
So now , example.com->shortened-url->example.com/home . I think it will work as you cannot change tumblr code .

Answer (score 0):

You can't use domain forwarding at GoDaddy in this case.   Domain forwarding only works to forward the entire domain to *another* domain.   In this case you want to forward the home page only (not the entire domain) to an internal page on the same domain (not another domain.)

The only way to configure this will be on the webserver that is hosting your site.   Since your domain is pointing at Tumblr's server, you will need to configure this at Tumblr.      If Tumblr is not letting you save the configuration, they may not support such a redirect away from the home page.